# C code working on online compilers but not on Leetcode

Tags: c

So there is a question on Leetcode to make a basic calculator (It just has operators `+` and `-`, and `(` and `)` brackets). For some reason the code is giving incorrect outputs on Leetcode and an online compiler gives correct outputs with the same test cases. What could be the issue here?

My Code(On Leetcode):

```
int pos = 0;

int calculate(char *s) {
    int sign = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    while (pos < len && s[pos] != ')') {
        if (s[pos] == '-') {
            sign = -1;
            printf("-\n");
        }
        else if (s[pos] == '+') {
            sign = 1;
            printf("+\n");
        }
        else if (s[pos] == '(') {
            pos++;
            sum += sign * calculate(s);
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        } else {
            int a = s[pos] - 48;
            if (a >= 0 && a < 10) {
                sum = sum + a * sign;
                printf("%d\n", sum);
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Code on the Compiler (Added a `main` function to call the function `calculate`):

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

int pos = 0;

int calculate(char *s) {
    int sign = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    while (pos < len && s[pos] != ')') {
        if (s[pos] == '-') {
            sign = -1;
            printf("-\n");
        }
        else if (s[pos] == '+') {
            sign = 1;
            printf("+\n");
        }
        else if (s[pos] == '(') {
            pos++;
            sum += sign * calculate(s);
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        } else {
            int a = s[pos] - 48;
            if (a >= 0 && a < 10) {
                sum = sum + a * sign;
                printf("%d\n", sum);
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    printf("\n\nResult: %d", calculate(" (2-1 + 2 -(2+2))+8"));
    return 0;
}
```

Is it an issue with how Leetcode handles global variables?
The testcases used:

Input: `s = "1 + 1"`
Input: `s = " 2-1 + 2 "`
Input: `s = "(1+(4+5+2)-3)+(6+8)"`

In all these testcases, the online compiler gives accurate outputs, whereas Leetcode gave correct output only for the first

Comment: Why are you using a global variable in the first place? There seems to be absolutely no need for that

Comment: And it's very much possible that Leetcode simply calls your function repeatedly rather than starting some program over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess:

> ... it's very much possible that Leetcode simply calls your function repeatedly rather than starting some program over and over again

–
UnholySheep

I suggest you implement your code without using your global variable; maybe that will eliminate the error.

Comment: Ok, that explains what is happening. So when they call it the second time, pos is not zero  but wherever it was left off last time.

Answer (score 1):

The tests you perform on the online computer are run one at a time, whereas the Leetcode server performs the tests as successive calls to `calculate()` without resetting the `pos` variable to `0` between calls. This explains why the first test succeeds and the subsequent ones fail.

This is a good lesson learned: avoid global variables, especially for internal state.

To avoid the global state, use an ancillary function, make `pos` a local variable and pass a pointer to it to the recursive function:

```
int calculate_internal(char *s, int len, int *pp) {
    int sign = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int pos = *pp;
    while (pos < len && s[pos] != ')') {
        if (s[pos] == '-') {
            sign = -1;
        } else
        if (s[pos] == '+') {
            sign = 1;
        } else
        if (s[pos] == '(') {
            pos++;
            sum += sign * calculate_internal(s, len, &pos);
        } else {
            int a = s[pos] - '0';
            if (a >= 0 && a < 10) {
                sum = sum + a * sign;
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }
    *pp = pos;
    return sum;
}

int calculate(char *s) {
    int pos = 0;
    return calculate_internal(s, strlen(s), &pos);
}
```

Note however that this approach cannot handle numbers with more than one digit.

Here is an alternative approach using a single recursive function, skipping the parenthesized expressions after recursive evaluation as suggested by [Caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77600658/4593267):

```
int calculate(char *s) {
    int sign = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while (*s && *s != ')') {
        char c = *s++;
        if (c == '-') {
            sign = -1;
        } else
        if (c == '+') {
            sign = 1;
        } else
        if (c == '(') {
            sum += sign * calculate(s);
            int level = 1;
            // skip past the matching )
            while (*s) {
                c = *s++;
                if (c == '(')
                    level++;
                else
                if (c == ')') {
                    if (--level == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            int value = c - '0';
            while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
                value = value * 10 + (*s++ - '0');
            }
            sum = sum + value * sign;
        } else {
            // ignore other characters
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: >Note however that this approach cannot handle numbers with more than one digit.

Damn just realised this, will have to revise my whole approach lol

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your code is that `pos` doesn't get reset from one call of `calculate()` to the next, if the tests are run sequentially. Try changing your `main()` function so that it calls `calculate()` several times with the different test cases and see if you get the right results.

One way to solve the problem is to handle `(` by finding the matching `)`, copying everything in between to a new string, and making the recursive `calculate()` call on that new string. That'll let you move `pos` inside `calculate()` and avoid the problem.